# Accessing PhpMyAdmin On Mac OS High Sierra w/ Amazon Lightsail

Tags: macos, phpmyadmin, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

I am trying to access PhpMyAdmin on my browser through an SSH tunnel on mac OS high sierra for setting up AWS Lightsail. I've downloaded my default SSH key pair and have adjusted permissions using

```
chmod 600 KEYNAME.PEM
```

I've tried ports 80 and 81 and have tried using port 1025. I do not get any errors in Terminal, but when launching via the URL: http://127.0.0.1:8888/phpmyadmin as suggested in Bitnami docs (with port adjusted to 1025 if 1025 is running), I get the error: "This site can’t be reached
127.0.0.1 refused to connect." and in Terminal: "channel 2: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
channel 2: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
channel 2: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused"

I'm using Google Chrome, 64-bit. I've tried turning firewall off, as well.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! I'm new at this. Thank you!

Comment: Hi Bitnami Engineer here. Did you make any change in any of the Apache's configuration? Please note that you only need to redirect all the incoming requests to the 8888 port to the 80 port in your instance `ssh -i ./yourfile.pem -N -L 8888:127.0.0.1:80 bitnami@YOUR_IP`. Let us know if that works

Comment: Thanks for responding. I haven’t made any changes to Apache. I’m following this document exactly: https://docs.bitnami.com/virtual-machine/components/phpmyadmin/ in terminal. I’ve already connected to MySQL database and set up SFTP. Am I missing a step?

Comment: Hi, you don't need to set SFTP to access phpMyAdmin. First of all, do you obtain the security error message when accessing to http://YOUR_IP/phpmyadmin? Can you use a different port when creating the tunnel `ssh -i ./yourfile.pem -N -L 8899:127.0.0.1:80 bitnami@YOUR_IP` and access phpMyAdmin using http://127.0.0.1:8899/phpmyadmin in the browser?

Comment: Hi Jota, finally revisiting this. using "ssh -N -L 8888:127.0.0.1:80 -i KEYFILE bitnami@STATIC_IP" I do not get any errors in terminal. When I access: http://localhost:8888, I get the "Congratulations! You are now running Bitnami Nginx 1.14.0-0 in the Cloud." page, but if I try to access http://localhost:8888/phpmyadmin, I get a "this site can't be reached" error. I've tried rebooting the instance. Any thoughts on why this is happening? I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! I'm not sure what did it, but I added a slash at the end of the URL I was accessing,  i.e. localhost:8888/phpmyadmin/ instead of localhost:8888/phpmyadmin. I also installed Cyberduck for mac and turned started/stopped my local servers with MAMP. Hoping this is helpful for someone else.